# App blocks with no error when redrawing GUI with setContentView

Tags: android, layout

I create a layout in code in onCreate. Inside this layout, i have spinner with registred listener. When user changes item in a spinner, new data is read and layout must be changed according to data. I do this with the same function as in onCreate (i create scrollview and other views and call setContentView(scollView) on the last line).

The layout changes correctly but everything blocks, spinner and buttons can't be clicked anymore. Logcat displays no error(only lots of GC freed x objects).

I tried calling scrollview.removeAllViews() before trying to redraw layout, but that doesn't help either.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are creating a whole new set of button and spinner objects. You need to register all the Listeners again to these new objects.

Comment: My function that creates layout is also registring listener for spinner. Problem is that spinner blocks and doesn't show its items when i click on it, let alone responding to click on a item.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in my onItemSelected function, where i forgot to change boolean "firstTime", so this function was called over and over.

```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (firstTime) {
            //do nothing (just change the flag) because we don't want this called during UI   building
            firstTime=false;
        }    
        else {
            posit=pos;
            String koda=Roaming.m.get(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
            Roaming.operaterji.clear();
            Roaming.parsePrices(json, koda);
            getAll();
            firstTime=true; //FORGET TO SET FLAG BACK TO TRUE, SO THIS WAS CALLED IN A LOOP
            makeGui();


        }           
    }
```